# Speedtest using python kivy

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, speed-test

I wrote the back end of a speed test and now I am trying to make a graphical user interface that dynamically shows the fluctuations in a speed test on a gauge until it gets the speed.
But I couldn't, I just made it in a static way for now.
any suggestions to make it?
and I want to make a loading effect too when the speed function is searching for the best server.
any ideas??
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to put the speedometer needle in its own `Image`, then use `Rotate` to set its angle. Something like this:

```
Image:
    source: 'needle.png'                                                                                                                                       
    canvas.before:                                                                                                                                             
        PushMatrix                                                                                                                                             
        Rotate:                                                                                                                                                
            angle: root.angle                                                                                                                                  
            axis: (0, 0, 1)                                                                                                                                    
            origin: (0,0,0) # position of the center of rotation of the needle                                                                                                                            
    canvas.after:                                                                                                                                              
        PopMatrix
```